# Best practice for AsyncTask: generic parameter vs multiple parameters?

Tags: java, android, generics, android-asynctask

If an `AsyncTask` needs to return a result it's common to create an interface for the callback and pass the class (that implements the interface) through the constructor.

Also if an `AsyncTask` (or any other non-activity class) needs access to the `ApplicationContext`, a `Context` parameter in the constructor can solve this issue.

But what If I need both and my caller is on the one hand an `Activity` (and therefore my `Context`) and on the other hand also my implementing interface?

Should the constructor of the `AsyncTask` look like `Constructor1` or `Constructor2`? What's the best practice here and why?

(If the right answer is `Constructor2`: should I merge my variables together to a single variable of the generic type `T`?)

```
public class MyTask<T extends Context & Callback> extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Callback callback;
    Context context; // Update: WeakReference<Context> should be used here to avoid memory leaks!

    // Constructor 1
    MyTask(Callback callback, Context context) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Constructor 2
    MyTask(T contextAndCallback) {
        this.callback = contextAndCallback;
        this.context = contextAndCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do stuff for which the context is needed for
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        callback.callbackMethod();
    }

    interface Callback {
        void callbackMethod();
    }
}
```

Best regards,
winklerrr

## Update 28.04

**Implement AsyncTask as an anonymous class**

Implementing the `AsyncTask` as an anonymous class inside my `Activity` would be a possible solution - yes.

But in my case I need the `AsyncTask` in different places - so I would hat to implement it multiple times which isn't a good solution to my mind.

**Are those the only options?**

I don't know if there are other solutions to my problem. I just came up with those two. If there is a better solution ("the" best practice) let me know!

Comment: Are you certain those are the only options? Have you explored the builder pattern? Consider replacing callbacks with queues?

Comment: Consider implementing your extended AsyncTask as an anonymous class wherever you activate it. This way it will have access to the class it was defined in and you don't have to mess with constructors to get what you need.

Comment: Making a Context accessible in `doInBackground` is a way to get memory leak. I would use WeakReference<Context> instead.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to archive.

- With the two parameters constructor you have the flexibility that use the context of any activity, service or wherever and implement the callback inside another object, like an extended TextView for example, and use the context that is bind to this view, via https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext() 
  and implementing your callback interface for example.  This let you do more useful things with your code and receive the callback event wherever you want.
- With the merged parameters way you lose this flexibility but you are sure that the object who is bind to this AsyncTask have a context and implements the callback. In other words the context and the callback together is a must. Can be useful if you what to force yourself and the other developers to use this AsyncTask with these conditions, of course there is a "hackish" ways like implement a fake object and get the context from another side but this will lead you to a hidden dependencies in your code and a lot of implements that will lead you to an unclear code and "non-elegant" solution.

From the architecture view the "best way", or wherever they show us at college, is never merge the parameters and returns for make your code more reusable from another sides and avoid hidden dependencies. Also you can try another approach like use a Service or queues.

Remember that the context can be GC and the AsyncTask can continue running.

Comment: So it's bad practice to pass a `Context` to an `AsyncTask`? What would be an alternative?

Comment: as [isabsent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674293/best-practice-for-asynctask-generic-parameter-vs-multiple-parameters/43675065?noredirect=1#comment74395435_43674293) says use WeakReference that contains a poiner that is not "watched" by the GC.. then when you want to use the context inside the AsyncTask check if is still alive